# Como solucionar problema con el or java

Tags: java

Estuve haciendo un progama cuando se presento un problema con el or || en realidad no logro comprender porqeu ocurre, si bien el progama corre con funcionalidad el resultado no es el deseado
Primeramente declaro el if con las condiciones separadas por un or pero este se va al else
el codigo es el siguiente

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class USSD {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Scanner lee=new Scanner(System.in);
     String cadena = null;

     char asterisco='*';
     String ayuda;
     int casos;
     char numeral='#';
     int stw = 0;
    ayuda=lee.nextLine();
    casos=Integer.parseInt(ayuda);


       for( int x=0;x<casos;x++) {

         cadena=lee.nextLine();
         int ling=cadena.length()-1;
        for(int a=0;a<cadena.length();a++) {
            if(cadena.charAt(a)==asterisco||cadena.charAt(a)==numeral||cadena.charAt(a)==0||cadena.charAt(a)==1||cadena.charAt(a)==2||cadena.charAt(a)==3||cadena.charAt(a)==4||cadena.charAt(a)==5||cadena.charAt(a)==6|cadena.charAt(a)==7||cadena.charAt(a)==8||cadena.charAt(a)==9) {

            }
            else {
                stw=1;
            }

        }
        if (cadena.charAt(0)==asterisco&&cadena.charAt(4)==asterisco&&cadena.charAt(ling)==numeral&&stw==0) {
         System.out.println("bien");
        }
        else {System.out.println("mal");} 



   }    




    }

}
```

el progama al usar la consola escribo *109*123# y me sale resultado "mal"
pero no en realidad no encuentro el problema de porque no me sale "bien"
estuve revisandolo on el debugger pero el error se da como ya dije en el or pues no se cumple y lo manda al else

ultimamente espero su ayuda :)

Comment: Aquí :  `cadena.charAt(a)==6|cadena.charAt(a)==7` te falta una raya vertical `|`.

Comment: El amigo de arriba tiene razón y te aconsejo que uses un switch. Solo por cuestiones esteticás (Oh por lo menos asi lo veo yo).

Comment: Si quieres usar expresiones regulares mira esto: `System.out.println("Escriba la cadena: ");
Scanner lee=new Scanner(System.in);
         
String cadena = lee.nextLine();
String resultado=(cadena.matches("[0-9*#]*")) ? "!Encontrado!" : "No encontrado";
System.out.println(resultado);

lee.close();` No soy experto en REGEX, pero éste funciona para determinar si en la cadena hay dígitos o hay los símbolos `*` o `#`. Si hay otro REGEX mejor alguien podrá decirlo, lo cierto es que esto es mejor resolverlo por esa vía. Te ahorras código y ganas en claridad y eficiencia.

Comment: Además de que te falta una | en algún or (como te han comentado los compañeros) cuando comparas texto, lo mejor es hacerlo con el método Equals. También te digo que las comparaciones que haces se pueden hacer con == y no debería darte problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código se puede simplificar usando una expresión regular:

```
System.out.println("Escriba la cadena: ");
Scanner lee=new Scanner(System.in);
String cadena = lee.nextLine();
String regex = ".*[0-9#*].*";
int stw =(cadena.matches(regex) ? 0 : 1;
int ling=cadena.length()-1;
char asterisco='*';
char numeral='#';

if (
      ling>4
      &&cadena.charAt(0)==asterisco
      &&cadena.charAt(4)==asterisco
      &&cadena.charAt(ling)==numeral
      &&stw==0
    ) 
{
     System.out.println("bien");
} else {
    System.out.println("mal");
} 
lee.close();
```

---

**Prueba 1:**

```
Escriba la cadena: 

*109*123#
bien
```

**Prueba 2:**

```
Escriba la cadena: 

*109*123#djdlj0w
mal
```